# C code for particle interaction in 2d

Tags: c, optimization

Imagine that you have a particle in each coordinate of a 2D Cartesian plane. Each particle emits a substance that difuses in all directions, with a decay over distance based on a Bessel function, and the other particles each absorb this substance.  Thus all particles at same distance from a given particle have the same influence on that particle. Something such as

[image: grid]

I'm calculating such an interaction using this code:

EDIT:31/03: Complete code for both.

```
 #include <stdio.h>  // para as rotinas de entrada e saída
 #include <stdlib.h> //
 #include <stdarg.h> // para importar os elementos da linha de comando
 #include <math.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <malloc.h>
 #include <time.h>

 #include"ran1.c"
 #include"bessel.c"
 #define tmax 90000
 #define N 50
 #define beta 0.001
 #define sigma 0.001
 #define pi acos(-1.0)
 #define trans 50000
 #define epsilon 0.1



 void condicoes_iniciais(double **xold,double **yold,double **a)
 {
   int l,j;

   long idum=-120534;
   for(l=0;l<= N; l++)
     {
       for(j=0;j<= N; j++)
        {
          a[l][j]=5.0; 
        }
     }

   for(l=0;l<= N; l++)
     {
      for(j=0;j<= N; j++)
       {
         while(a[l][j]>4.4)
         a[l][j]=4.1+ran1(& idum);
       }
     }

   for(l=0;l<= N; l++)
    {
     for(j=0;j<= N; j++)
      {
       xold[l][j]=0.1*ran1(& idum);
      }
    }
   for(l=0;l<= N; l++)
    {
     for(j=0;j<= N; j++)
      {
       yold[l][j]=0.1*ran1(& idum);
      }
    }
 }


 void Matriz_Bessel(double **Bess,double gama)
 {
   int x,y;
   double r;
    for(x=0;x<=N;x++)
     {
      for(y=0;y<=N;y++)
       {
        if(y!=0 || x!=0)
        {
         r = gama*sqrt(x*x +y*y);
         Bess[x][y] = bessk0(r);
        }
       }
     }
 }

 void acoplamento(int x, int y,double **xold, double *Acopl,double **Bess)
 {
   int j, i, h, k,xdist, ydist;
   int Nmeio = N/2;
   double Xf;
   Xf = 0;

   for(i=0;i<=N;i++)
    {
     for(j=0;j<=N;j++)
      {
       h = x+i;
       k = y+j;
       ydist = j;
       xdist = i;

       if(i>Nmeio)
        {
         h = x +i;
         xdist = (N+1) -h +x;
        }
       if(h>N)
        {
         h=h-(N+1);
         xdist = x-h;
         if(xdist >Nmeio){xdist = i;
        }
       }

       if(j>Nmeio)
        {
         k = y +j;
         ydist = (N+1) -k +y;
        }

       if(k>N)
        {
         k=k-(N+1);
         ydist = y-k;
         if(ydist >Nmeio){ydist = j;
        }
       }

       if(ydist!=0 || xdist!=0)
        {
         Xf = Xf +Bess[xdist][ydist]*xold[h][k];
        }
     }
    }
   *Acopl = Xf;
 }

 void constante(double *c, double gama, double **Bess){
   double soma;
   int x, y;
   soma = 0;

   for(x=0;x<=(N/2);x++)
    {
     for(y=0;y<=(N/2);y++)
      {
       if(y!=0 || x!=0)
        {
         soma = soma +Bess[x][y];
        }
      }
    }
   *c = (1/(4*soma));
 }


 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
   double **xold, **xnew, **yold, **ynew, **a;
   double gama, C;
   int x,y;
   int t,i;
   double  Mn, acopl;
   char arqnome[100];
   FILE *fout;
   double **Bess;
   Bess= (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)*(N+3));
   for(i=0; i<(N+3); i++){Bess[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*   (N+3));}
   xold= (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)*(N+3));
   for(i=0; i<(N+3); i++){xold[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*  (N+3));}
   yold= (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)*(N+3));
   for(i=0; i<(N+3); i++){yold[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*(N+3));}
   xnew= (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)*(N+3));
   for(i=0; i<(N+3); i++){xnew[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*(N+3));}
   ynew= (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)*(N+3));
   for(i=0; i<(N+3); i++){ynew[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*(N+3));}
   a= (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)*(N+3));
    for(i=0; i<(N+3); i++){a[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*(N+3));}

   srand (time(NULL));

   gama = 0.005;
   sprintf(arqnome,"serie_%.3f_%.3f.dat",gama,epsilon);
   fout = fopen(arqnome,"w");


   Matriz_Bessel(Bess,gama);
   condicoes_iniciais(xold,yold,a);

   a[0][0] = 4.1;
   a[N/2][N/2] = 4.3;


   constante(&C, gama,Bess);
     for(t=0;t<=tmax;t++)
     {
       Mn = 0;
       for(x=0;x<=N;x++)
          {
            for(y=0;y<=N;y++)
             {
               acoplamento(x,y,xold,&acopl,Bess);
               xnew[x][y] = (a[x][y]/(1+xold[x][y]*xold[x][y])) +yold[x][y] + epsilon*C*acopl;
               ynew[x][y] = yold[x][y] - sigma*xold[x][y] - beta;
               Mn = Mn + xnew[x][y];
               xold[x][y] = xnew[x][y];
               yold[x][y] = ynew[x][y];
              }
         } 
        if(t>trans){fprintf(fout,"%d %f %f %f %f %f\n",(t-trans),xold[0][0],yold[0][0],xold[N/2][N/2],yold[N/2][N/2],Mn/((N+1)*(N+1)));}
     }
   return 0;
 }
```

`Bess[N][N]` is the Bessel function for each radius, with is calculated using numerical recipes. This program take around 1 hour to finish.

With the sugestion of Francis i have

```
 #include <fftw3.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 #include"bessel.c"
 #include"ran1.c"
 #define tmax 90000
 #define beta 0.001
 #define N 50
 #define sigma 0.001
 #define pi acos(-1.0)
 #define trans 50000
 #define epsilon 0.1


 void condicoes_iniciais(double *xold,double *yold,double *a)
 {
   int l;
   long idum=-120534;
   for(l=0;l<= N*N; l++){
       a[l]=5.0;}

   for(l=0;l<= N*N; l++){
       while(a[l]>4.4)
         a[l]=4.1+ran1(& idum);}

   for(l=0;l<=N* N; l++){
       xold[l]=0.1*ran1(& idum);
       yold[l]=0.1*ran1(& idum);}
   a[0]=4.1;
   a[N]=4.4;
 }


 void Matriz_Bessel(double *bessel,double gama)
 {

   int x,y,i,j;
   double dist;
   for(x=0,i=-N/2;x<N;x++,i++)
    {
      for(y=0,j=-N/2;y<N;y++,j++)
       {
         double dist=sqrt(i*i+j*j);
          if(dist>0){
            bessel[x*N+y]=bessk0(gama*dist);
            }
       else{
         bessel[x*N+y]=1;
         }
       }
    }
  }


  void constante(double *c, double *bessel)
  {
   int x;
   int y;
   double soma = 0;
   for(x=0;x<N;x++){
     for(y=0;y<N;y++){
       soma = soma + bessel[x*N+y];
     }}
   *c =(1/(4*soma));
 }

 int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

   double *xnew=fftw_malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N);
   double *acopl=fftw_malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N);
   double *xold=malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N);

   double *yold = malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N);
   double *a = malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N);

   fftw_complex *xfourier;
   xfourier = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*(N/2+1)*N);

   fftw_complex *aux;
   aux= (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*(N/2+1)*N);

   double *bessel= fftw_malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N);

   fftw_complex *besself;
   besself=fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*(N/2+1)*N);

   double scale=1.0/(N*N);
   int t,i;
   double gama,Mn,C;
   gama = 0.005;

   char arqnome[1000];
   FILE *fout;
   sprintf(arqnome,"opt2_tamanho_plato_%.3f_%d.dat",gama,N);
   fout = fopen(arqnome,"w");

   //initial
   printf("initial\n");
   condicoes_iniciais(xold,yold,a);
   //xold[(N/2)*N+N/2]=1;

   // fftw_plan
   printf("fftw_plan\n");
   fftw_plan plan;
   plan=fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(N, N, xnew, xfourier, FFTW_MEASURE |    FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT);

   fftw_plan planb;
   planb=fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(N, N,(double*) bessel, besself, FFTW_MEASURE);

   fftw_plan plani;
   plani=fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d(N, N, aux, acopl, FFTW_MEASURE);

   Matriz_Bessel(bessel,gama);
   constante(&C, bessel);
   fftw_execute(planb);


   //time loop
   printf("time loop\n");
   for(t=0;t<=tmax;t++){
     //convolution= products in fourier space
     fftw_execute(plan);
     for(i=0;i<N*(N/2+1);i++){
       aux[i][0]=(xfourier[i][0]*besself[i][0]-xfourier[i][2]*besself[i][3]);
       aux[i][4]=(xfourier[i][0]*besself[i][5]+xfourier[i][6]*besself[i][0]);
     }

     fftw_execute(plani);//xnew is updated
     Mn = 0;
     for(i=0;i<N*N;i++){
       xnew[i]=(a[i]/(1+xold[i]*xold[i])) +yold[i] + epsilon*C*  (acopl[i]/(double)(N*N));
       yold[i] = yold[i] - sigma*xold[i] - beta;
       Mn = Mn +xnew[i];
     }
       memcpy(xold,xnew,N*N*sizeof(double));
     if(t>trans){fprintf(fout,"%d %f %f %f %f %f\n",(t-trans),xold[0],yold[0],xold[N],yold[N],Mn/((N+1)*(N+1)));}

   }
   printf("destroy\n");

   fftw_destroy_plan(plan);  
   fftw_destroy_plan(plani);  
   fftw_destroy_plan(planb);  

   printf("free\n");

   fftw_free(bessel);
   fftw_free(xnew);
   fftw_free(xold);
   fftw_free(yold);
   fftw_free(besself);
   fftw_free(xfourier);

   return 0;
 }

With take around 1min to finish, but i got this results
```

[image: rulkov]

The scale factor on fftw3 code have to be that value. I dont know how make it work.

Comment: If **you have a particle in each coordinate** and **Each particle emits a substance that difuses in all directions** and **the other particles each absorb this substance** -- how is this not a steady-state problem? Are you looking for saturation rate, changing emission/adsorption, what?

Comment: Its a simulation of a neuronal system, using a map for each neuron and with an accoupling between based in a diffusion of a substance. And im looking for some kind of sinchronization between then.

Comment: That makes more sense, you are looking for time to stead-state based on emission/adsorption rates of some type. More like a response to a step-input.

Answer (score 3):

The operation you are describing is called a [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution). Let `f(x,y)` be your periodic sources and `B(x,y)` the Bessel function. You are trying to compute :

[image: eq]

Discretized on a grid of size `N+1`, it writes :

[image: eq2]

Since this sum is performed at all points, the complexity is very high : `O(N^4)`. It means that the number of operations to performed is of the magnitude of `N*N*N*N`. **How to reduce this complexity ?**

- If `B(x,y)` gets rapidly small as the distance increases, long-range interactions may be neglected and the window of the convolution may be reduced. It will affect the precision of the output and it may not be useful for your problem. Let `N_W<<N` be the size of this window. The sum now writes :

[image: eq3]

And the number of operations to be performed is about `N*N*N_W*N_W<<N^4`.
Yet, from a practical point of view, the kernel has to be very small to make the method described above very interesting. Since [the Bessel functions decrease slowly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#cite_ref-30) ([from Abramowitz and Stegun: Handbook of Mathematical Functions, p364](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_364.htm)) (approx 1/sqrt(x)), the previous method is unlikely to be successful.

- According to the [convolution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem), ***the [Discrete Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) may be applied to convolve periodic signals ! A convolution in distance space resumes to products of corresponding wavelength in the Fourier space.***

The [algorithm is the following](http://ocw.usu.edu/Electrical_and_Computer_Engineering/Signals_and_Systems/9_5node5.html) :

1 Compute the DFT of `f`, named `hatf`

2 Compute the DFT of `B`, named `hatB`

3 For all frequencies `p,q`, perform the product :
    `hatf*(p,q)=hatf(p,q)*hatB(p,q)`

4 Inverse the DFT to get `f*`

The method described above is really efficient since its complexity is the one of 2D DFT, that is `N*N*log(N)`. Moreover, dedicated libraries such as [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) makes it easy to implement. Take a look at [`fftw_plan fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d`](http://fftw.org/doc/Real_002ddata-DFTs.html#Real_002ddata-DFTs) and be careful about the [data layout](http://fftw.org/doc/Real_002ddata-DFT-Array-Format.html#Real_002ddata-DFT-Array-Format).

EDIT : I still think there is a may to make it work... Here is a starting code, compile it by `gcc main.c -o main -lfftw3 -lm`

```
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int save_image(int N,double* data,int nb){
    char filename[1000];
    sprintf(filename,"xxx%d.vtk",nb);
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen (filename,"w");
    if (pFile!=NULL)
    {
        fputs ("# vtk DataFile Version 2.0\n",pFile);
        fputs ("Volume example\n",pFile);
        fputs ("ASCII\n",pFile);
        fputs ("DATASET STRUCTURED_POINTS\n",pFile);
        fprintf(pFile,"DIMENSIONS %d %d 1\n",N,N);
        fputs ("ASPECT_RATIO 1 1 1\n",pFile);
        fputs ("ORIGIN 0 0 0\n",pFile);
        fprintf(pFile,"POINT_DATA %d\n",N*N);
        fputs ("SCALARS volume_scalars float 1\n",pFile);
        fputs ("LOOKUP_TABLE default\n",pFile);
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<N*N;i++){
            fprintf(pFile,"%f ",data[i]);
        }

        fclose (pFile);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int N=64;
    double *xnew=fftw_malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N);
    double *xold=fftw_malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N);

    double *yold=fftw_malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N);


    fftw_complex *xfourier=fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*(N/2+1)*N);
    double *bessel=fftw_malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N);
    fftw_complex *besself=fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*(N/2+1)*N);

    //initial
    printf("initial\n");
    memset(xold,0,sizeof(double)*N*N);
    memset(yold,0,sizeof(double)*N*N);
    xold[(N/2)*N+N/2]=1;

    // fftw_plan
    printf("fftw_plan\n");
    fftw_plan plan;
    plan=fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(N, N, xold, xfourier, FFTW_ESTIMATE | FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT);
    fftw_plan planb;
    planb=fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(N, N,(double*) bessel, besself, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_plan plani;
    plani=fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d(N, N, xfourier, xnew, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    //bessel function
    //crude approximate of bessel...
    printf("bessel function\n");
    double dx=1.0/(double)N;
    double dy=1.0/(double)N;
    int x,y;int i,j;
    for(x=0,i=-N/2;x<N;x++,i++){
        for(y=0,j=-N/2;y<N;y++,j++){
            double dist=sqrt(dx*dx*(i*i+j*j));
            double range=0.01;
            dist=dist/range;
            if(dist>0){
                bessel[x*N+y]=sqrt(2./(M_PI*dist))*cos(dist-M_PI/4.0);
            }else{
                bessel[x*N+y]=1;
            }
        }
    }
    fftw_execute(planb);

    fftw_destroy_plan(planb); 
    fftw_free(bessel);


    //time loop
    printf("time loop\n");
    int t,tmax=100;
    for(t=0;t<=tmax;t++){
        save_image(N,xold,t);
        printf("t=%d\n",t);
        //convolution= products in fourier space
        fftw_execute(plan);
        double scale=1.0/((double)N*N);
        //scale*=scale; //may be needed to correct scaling
        for(i=0;i<N*(N/2+1);i++){
            xfourier[i][0]=(xfourier[i][0]*besself[i][0]-xfourier[i][1]*besself[i][1])*scale;
            xfourier[i][1]=(xfourier[i][0]*besself[i][1]+xfourier[i][1]*besself[i][0])*scale;
        }

        fftw_execute(plani);//xnew is updated

        double C=1;double epsilon=1; double a=1; double beta=1;double sigma=1;
        for(i=0;i<N*N;i++){
            xnew[i]=(a/(1+xold[i]*xold[i])) +yold[i] + epsilon*C*xnew[i];
            yold[i] = yold[i] - sigma*xold[i] - beta;
        }
        memcpy(xold,xnew,N*N*sizeof(double));

    }
    printf("destroy\n");

    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);  
    fftw_destroy_plan(plani);  
    // fftw_destroy_plan(planb);  

    printf("free\n");

    fftw_free(xnew);
    fftw_free(xold);
    fftw_free(yold);
    fftw_free(besself);
    fftw_free(xfourier);

    return 0;
}
```

It produces some vtk images of `xold` which may be opened by the paraview software. It is likely that saving the images slow down the computations...
My coefficients are wrong, so the output is wrong...

EDIT : Here is piece of code based on yours, to be compiled by `gcc main.c -o main -lfftw3 -lm`. I found [bessk0.c](ftp://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/cs/robotics/scohen/nr/bessk0.c) and [bessi0.c](http://cosmo.nyu.edu/mb144/sdss-lf/src/bessi0.c).

The code writes :

```
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include"bessi0.c"
#include"bessk0.c"
    //#include"bessel.c"
    //#include"ran1.c"
#define tmax 90000
#define beta 0.001
#define N 50
#define sigma 0.001
#define pi acos(-1.0)
#define trans 50000
#define epsilon 0.1

    double ran1(long* idum){
        return ((double)rand())/((double)RAND_MAX);
    }

    void condicoes_iniciais(double *xold,double *yold,double *a)
    {
        int l;
        long idum=-120534;
        for(l=0;l<= N*N; l++){
            a[l]=5.0;}

        for(l=0;l<= N*N; l++){
            while(a[l]>4.4)
                a[l]=4.1+ran1(& idum);}

        for(l=0;l<=N* N; l++){
            xold[l]=0.1*ran1(& idum);
            yold[l]=0.1*ran1(& idum);
            //printf("%g %g %g\n",xold[l],yold[l],a[l]);
        }
        a[0]=4.1;
        a[N]=4.4;


    }


    void Matriz_Bessel(double *bessel,double gama)
    {

        int x,y,i,j;
        double dist;
        for(x=0,i=-N/2;x<N;x++,i++)
        {
            for(y=0,j=-N/2;y<N;y++,j++)
            {
                double dist=sqrt(i*i+j*j);
                if(dist>0){

                    bessel[x*N+y]=bessk0(gama*dist);
                    //printf("%g %g\n",dist,bessel[x*N+y]);
                }
                else{
                    bessel[x*N+y]=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    void constante(double *c, double *bessel)
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        double soma = 0;
        for(x=0;x<N;x++){
            for(y=0;y<N;y++){
                soma = soma + bessel[x*N+y];
            }}
        // *c =(1.0/(4.0*soma));
        *c =(1.0/(soma));
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

        //srand (time(NULL));
        srand (0);

        double *xnew=fftw_malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N);
        double *acopl=fftw_malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N);
        double *xold=malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N);

        double *yold = malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N);
        double *a = malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N);

        fftw_complex *xfourier;
        xfourier = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*(N/2+1)*N);

        fftw_complex *aux;
        aux= (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*(N/2+1)*N);

        double *bessel= fftw_malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N);

        fftw_complex *besself;
        besself=fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*(N/2+1)*N);

        double scale=1.0/((double)N*N);
        int t,i;
        double gama,Mn,C;
        gama = 0.005;

        char arqnome[1000];
        FILE *fout;
        sprintf(arqnome,"opt2_tamanho_plato_%.3f_%d.dat",gama,N);
        fout = fopen(arqnome,"w");

        //initial
        printf("initial\n");
        condicoes_iniciais(xold,yold,a);
        //xold[(N/2)*N+N/2]=1;

        // fftw_plan
        printf("fftw_plan\n");
        fftw_plan plan;
        plan=fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(N, N, xnew, xfourier, FFTW_MEASURE |    FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT);

        fftw_plan planb;
        planb=fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(N, N, bessel, besself, FFTW_MEASURE);

        fftw_plan plani;
        plani=fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d(N, N, aux, acopl, FFTW_MEASURE);

        Matriz_Bessel(bessel,gama);
        constante(&C, bessel);
        fftw_execute(planb);


        //time loop
        printf("time loop\n");
        for(t=0;t<=tmax;t++){
            //convolution= products in fourier space
            fftw_execute(plan);
            for(i=0;i<N*(N/2+1);i++){
                aux[i][0]=(xfourier[i][0]*besself[i][0]-xfourier[i][1]*besself[i][1]);
                aux[i][1]=(xfourier[i][0]*besself[i][1]+xfourier[i][1]*besself[i][0]);
            }

            fftw_execute(plani);//xnew is updated
            Mn = 0;
            for(i=0;i<N*N;i++){
                xnew[i]=(a[i]/(1+xold[i]*xold[i])) +yold[i] + epsilon*C*  (acopl[i]/(double)(N*N));
                yold[i] = yold[i] - sigma*xold[i] - beta;
                Mn = Mn +xnew[i];
            }
            memcpy(xold,xnew,N*N*sizeof(double));
            if(t>trans){fprintf(fout,"%d %f %f %f %f %f\n",(t-trans),xold[0],yold[0],xold[N],yold[N],Mn/((N+1)*(N+1)));}

        }
        printf("destroy\n");

        fftw_destroy_plan(plan);  
        fftw_destroy_plan(plani);  
        fftw_destroy_plan(planb);  

        printf("free\n");

        fftw_free(bessel);
        fftw_free(xnew);
        fftw_free(xold);
        fftw_free(yold);
        fftw_free(besself);
        fftw_free(xfourier);

        fftw_free(aux);
        fftw_free(acopl);

        return 0;
    }
```

The result is the following :
[image: plot]

The lines :

```
aux[i][0]=(xfourier[i][0]*besself[i][0]-xfourier[i][1]*besself[i][1]);
aux[i][1]=(xfourier[i][0]*besself[i][1]+xfourier[i][1]*besself[i][0]);
```

Correspond to product of complex numbers. `aux[i]` is a complex number, `aux[i][0]` is its real part and `aux[i][1]` its imaginary part. Hence `aux[i][4]` does not correspond to something meaningful. These complex numbers correspond to magnitudes of frequencies in the [Fourier space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform).

I also modified the constant : `*c =(1.0/(soma));`

Do not forget to add `srand(0)` if you wish to compare outputs and build the initial state in the same way.

Comment: The problem is, my f in this case chance for each particle and each time. On my code is that xold [xdist] [ydist]. And my Bess [N] [N] I calculate only once, when the program start, because his argument not chance at time, and save this values on a matrix, i just call them there. How can be calculate 2 DFT for each particle each time be more quickly? My code its just a sum of matrix.

Comment: In your case, i though `f(x,y)` was `xold(x,y)`. The DFT is called only 3 times, not `N*N` times : that is why it is so efficient. It is the DFT of array `xold`, the whole array at once, not the DFT of the scalar `xold(x,y)` (hard to define by the way).

Comment: Ok...My answer does not work because `xold` is updated within the for loop, so that `xnew[x][y]` depends directly on `xnew[x][y-1]` . My answer would have been useful if `xold[x][y]=xnew[x][y]` was performed in a separe for loop. Hence, I will delete my answer within a few hours. Is it crucial to have `xold` updated within the for loop ? What would happen if the update were placed in a second pair of for loops ?

Comment: Something like `for(t...){for(x){for(y){acoplamento(x,y,xold,&acopl,Bess);}}for(x){for(y){xold[x][y]=xnew[x][y];}}}`

Comment: I can do this, i just put this in the same `for` just for the program not make two `for` and make the simulation timer lower. My `xnew[x][y]` will only depend of my `xnew[x][y]` in the previous time, i.e, my `xold[x][y]`, plus a coupling term (acoplamento function). `t` in this program its like a time.

Comment: I need to use `a[x][y]` because this a will make the dynamics of each particle different. This `a[x][y]` is randomly distributed between 4.1 and 4.4. C its a normalization constant that come from a Green function. I use to calculate the bessel function from numerical recipes book. `acopl` its like a average weighted of all `xold[x][y]`.

Comment: This is just the main program. I will check if have some phase synchronization and after this I will put some periodic external signal to see if i can "destroy" this sincronization, and this external signal will be apply just on a portion of particle, not in all of them.

Comment: ok. Im reading some articles and this might work. I just not understand what is that `scale` and `M_PI` its something int he `fft` library? T its the time so my xnew its based on his value at the previous time so i will need to change for this right?` ynew[x][y] = yold[x][y] - sigma*xold[x][y] - beta;` .

Comment: According to the [documentation of fftw](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Real_002ddata-DFTs.html#Real_002ddata-DFTs) >FFTW computes an unnormalized transform: computing an r2c followed by a c2r transform (or vice versa) will result in the original data multiplied by the size of the transform (product  logical dimensions). There is a need for a `scale`. `M_PI` is pi, that is 3.1415 (and a few more digits). The fftw plans perform the change from `xold` to `xfourier` and `xfourier` to `xnew`. I did not find why storing `ynew` was necessary... feel free to adapt that code to your situation !

Comment: I will try see more about this `fft`. But i need to see that `xnew`after `epsilon*C` it might be wrong. `xnew` its like a phase of an oscilator, and the `acopl` its like the mean field. What you do looks like the xnew was replace by the mean field.

Comment: The `xnew` after the `epsilon*C` is the output of the convolution, that is `acopl` in your code, except that it is computed at once, as an array, thanks to the Fast Fourier Transform.

Comment: I try with the same value I already used, but doesn't work, looks like this acopl term is "weaker" than I use on my program. I dont understand 'besself' she not got an upgrade on program, and not initialized.

Comment: The `scale` parameter may have to be changed. The array `besself` is the FFT of the array `bessel`. It is initialized as ` fftw_execute(planb);` is called.

Comment: I know what is wrong with this `fftw`. Because of this `Xf = Xf +Bess[xdist][ydist]*xold[h][k]`. In `fftw` you make this product using `Bess[h][k]*xold[h][k]`. The indices `xdist` and `ydist` from bessel represent distance from a calculate neuron, and the indices `h` and `k` from `xold` represent the position of the neuron at `xdist` and `ydist` from a calculate neuron.

Comment: My bessel.c is exactly the 2 bessel function you found. Not need to be exactly the same initial state, I change all simulation to see if the initial state will change the final result, but to change. I will see others results if with this will reproduce too. Ty with help you help a lot.

Comment: More one problem hahaha.. for `gama=0.005` your code do the same of mine, but if I change to `gama=1`, your code reproduce exactly the same of `gama=0.005`, but for `gama=1` it will be more like the wrong figure I post.

Answer (score 2):

You could perhaps use the symmetry of the grid to reduce the number of computations needed.  Especially so if you are modelling an infinite periodic system, as apparent wrap-around logic makes me think you may be doing.

Consider:

- the same influence is exerted on a particle at the coordinates `[35][35]` by particles at `[35 - x][35]`, `[35 + x][35]`, `[35][35 - x]`, and `[35][35 + x]`, for any x; also,
- another influence is exerted equally by the particles at `[35 - x][35 - x]`, `[35 + x][35 - x]`, `[35 - x][35 + x]`, and `[35 + x][35 + x]`, for any; and
- yet another influence is exerted equally by the particles at `[35 + x][35 + y]`, `[35 + x][35 - y]`, `[35 - x][35 + y]`, `[35 - x][35 - y]`, `[35 + y][35 + x]`, `[35 + y][35 - x]`, `[35 - y][35 + x]`, and `[35 - y][35 - x]`, for any `x != y`.

You should be able to speed your computation by a little less than a factor of 8 by using those equivalences.

If indeed you are simulating an infinite periodic system, however, then I observe that your approach incorporates a bias: by computing the influences from a square grid, you are including the influence of some of the particles at distances between `N` and `sqrt(2) * N` from the target, but not of others.  You should compute on a (virtual) disc, instead, to avoid such bias.

Furthermore, the appearance of input parameters `x` and `y` leads me to suppose that you are performing that computation once for each grid position.  If, again, you are modelling an infinite, periodic grid with an emitter at each grid point, and in which each point's influence depends only on distance, then *every point will experience the same influence*.  You could cut your runtime several thousand-fold, **and** reduce the asymptotic complexity of your algorithm if you can make use of that.

Comment: Yes, x and y are the coordinates of each particles. xold its the value of a function for each particle that is calculate in other part of the program. The radius of influence goes to R=1 to R=sqrt(2*((N-1)/2)^2). And every point will experience the same influence at the same radius, because this influence decay with a bessel function.